# Homemade blackberry wine

Tags: red-wine

I made some blackberry wine last year. I tasted sone last night and there is a very slight fizz to it, is it at all possible to get rid of this fizz, if so how? I'm clearly a total novice, and any help/advice is very much appreciated indeed!

Answer (score 7):

Is it already bottled, or is it still in a carboy or other bulk vessel?

If you made the wine from fresh fruit and it's still in a bulk vessel, your best bet is to just wait.  Leave it in a carboy with an airlock and the gas will come out of suspension.  Racking it will help relieve the wine of its CO<sub>2</sub>, but be careful not to expose it to too much oxygen whilst racking.  Wine tends to give up its gas after a year of bulk aging and a handful of rackings.

If you made the wine from a kit and it should be ready by now, or if you've already bottled it, you can de-gas the wine.  There are a few ways to do this.  First, if you let the temperature of the wine go up a little, the wine will give up some CO<sub>2</sub> naturally.  Don't go too high, as staling and oxidation rates increase as temps go up.  If you currently have it at 55F, allow it to go to, say, 67F for a few days.

Alternatively, you can force the CO<sub>2</sub> out of suspension with some help from a vacuum.  If it is in bottles, you can use a [Vacu Vin](http://www.vacuvin.com/Vacuum_Wine_Saver_286_270_267.html) or similar product to pull the gas out.  If it's in a bulk vessel, you can hook up a vacuum pump.  Search the web for "Degassing wine" for more information and detailed instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to provide nucleation sites to promote the CO<sub>2</sub> escaping is to add a little sugar or Splenda<sup>tm</sup> (the latter will really release the gas). I'd do this sparingly because it will sweeten the wine, but if it is fairly dry to start with, most people prefer some sweetness to cut the alcohol bite. This really is true with fruit ciders and wines with more subtle flavors such as pear, peach, and apple.